# How do I decrement a char pointer in c to point to specifc first characters

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers, decrement

say I declare a char pointer in the following way:

```
char *str = "123456";
```

and I want to point to the sub string `"123"`, how do I decrement the pointer so that the pointer `str` points to 123?

I know I can increment the pointer to point to the latter part of the string:

```
// now str will point to 456
str+=3;
```

but what about the beginning of the string/trimming the end of `str` string using the decrement `--`/`-=` operator, is this possible?

Comment: Technically, `"123"` is not a sub-string in the original string, as there's no null-termination in the `"123"` part.

Comment: So what should I call it then?

Comment: That's not how strings work. The pointer marks the start of the string (so it already points to `"123"`), but the end of the string is marked by the `\0` character. Therefore, if you want `str` to point to the string `"123"`, you have to replace the character `4` with `\0`

Comment: Call it whatever you want, but remember, you have to make it a substring, it's not one, in it's current form.

Comment: If you **just** want to print 3 characters from a longer string, you can use `printf("%.3s", "123456");` or `int n = 3; printf("%.*s", n, "123456")`

Comment: Funny Felix G I tried that and when ran on linux I get a stack smashing error?

Comment: Chopping the end of a string does not work simply with pointer manipulation. Instead you must insert terminator. This will change the initial string in memory. And in your case it is not possible as you use a string literal which is not allowed to be modified. You will need to copy the part of the string somewhere else

Comment: @asd23553 Well, that's because in this particular case it's a string literal, and those can't be modified. So you would need to make a copy first, and then trim it (or just stop copying at the right time and insert a `\0`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are somehow already pointing to the string 123....the only differene is that it is null terminated at the 7th character, after the '6' and therefore you get the string 123456

If you are looking for a "left" method, to take only the initial 3 characters, probably you need to have a look to the function strncpy. As an alternative, you can also terminate the string by putting the 4th character to null. In the second way anyway, you are altering the original content you had and you are losing information.

Comment: Remember to properly terminate *strings* (they're not really strings otherwise) obtained from `strncpy()`

Comment: Beware of `strncpy`, it does not necessarily what you think it does.

Comment: `As an alternative, you can also terminate the string by putting the 4th character to null.` will not work if the source is a string literal.